# How can I get KornShell to display the date and time in the prompt?

Tags: ksh, aix, prompt

On my AIX box, which is using `ksh` as the default shell, I'd like the prompt to show both the date and time followed by a newline `\n`, along with the name of the machine, and the working directory.

Something like:

```
2014/08/05 10:58:43
[username]machinename:/some/path/here $
```

I've tried the following:

```
unset _Y _M _D _h _m _s
eval $(date "+_Y=%Y;_M=%m;_D=%d;_h=%H;_m=%M;_s=%S")
((SECONDS=3600*${_h#0}+60*${_m#0}+${_s#0}))
typeset -Z2 _h _m _s
_tsub="(_m=(SECONDS/60%60)) == (_h=(SECONDS/3600%24)) + (_s=(SECONDS%60))"
_timehm='${_x[_tsub]}$_h:${_m}'
_timehms='${_x[_tsub]}$_h:$_m:${_s}'
_timedhms=$_Y'/'$_M'/'$_D" "'${_x[_tsub]}$_h:$_m:${_s}'

PS1="$_timedhms'\n' "'[USERNAME]MACHINE:${PWD#$HOME/} $ '
```

However, there is no newline between the date/time and the rest of the prompt.  It seems now matter what the combination of quotes I try, I cannot get a newline to appear in PS1.

Comment: Double quoted strings in ksh do not automatically interpret `\n` as a newline. As Gnouc demonstrates there are workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the literal newline in `PS1`:

```
PS1="$_timedhms
> [USERNAME]MACHINE:${PWD#$HOME/} $ "
```

or using `$'\n'` with ksh93:

```
PS1="$_timedhms$'\n' [USERNAME]MACHINE:${PWD#$HOME/} $ "
```

Comment: The literal newline works, however the `$'\n'` does not appear to work at all.  I just get an `n` displayed inline.

Comment: It seems only work with ksh93. Updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

There is pretty simple way to do this:

```
export PS1=$(echo "\033[01;33m"`date +%D`" "`date +%T`"\033[0m""\n"`whoami`@"\033[3;36m"`hostname`"\033[0m"':$PWD'#)
```

If you want to set this permanently add the entry to '/etc/profile'.

Comment: Or ~/.profile is you don't want to force it on everyone

Comment: Speaking of permanently — this sets the prompt to permanently/perpetually display the *current* date/time (i.e., the instant when you login, or otherwise set the prompt string), rather than the date/time when the prompt is *issued*.