# why is EXPORT PS1 in my .profile getting clobbered?

Tags: ksh, prompt, profile

In this question [How can I get KornShell to display the date and time in the prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148550/how-can-i-get-kornshell-to-display-the-date-and-time-in-the-prompt) all the variables are visible in ksh except PS1 which appears to be getting replaced somehow.

How can I determine what is resetting PS1 After my .profile is processed?

Comment: Is ksh your default shell? E,g, when you run `grep $USER /etc/passwd | cut -d":" -f7` is `/bin/ksh` displayed? If not, then it's possible that your default shell's startup file is being executed.

Comment: is `$ENV` set ?

Comment: @Warwick yes, the default shell is ksh

Comment: Hmmmm, if you don't mind running a command that might take a long time, you could run `sudo find / | xargs grep PS1`. You could also narrow it down to the likely directories so instead of `/`, you could search `/etc`, `/home`... You would get a list of files containing PS1 which may be helpful in identifying what is causing this.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - yes $ENV is visible from my ksh.

Comment: Then that's probably where PS1 is (and should be) defined.

Comment: I'm an idiot - it turns out my .envfile has PS1 in it.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas - I'll move my PS1 mods to .envfile

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @StéphaneChazelas - I was able to get my PS1 prompt exactly the way I want it.

I remove the customizations from my `.profile` file, and appended the following to my `.envfile`.  I was not aware of this, but the `.envfile` is processed *after* the `.profile` file.

```
#set the prompt to include the date and time
set -o allexport
unset _Y _M _D _h _m _s
eval $(date "+_Y=%Y;_M=%m;_D=%d;_h=%H;_m=%M;_s=%S")
((SECONDS = 3600*${_h#0}+60*${_m#0}+${_s#0}))
typeset -Z2 _h _m _s
_tsub="(_m=(SECONDS/60%60)) == (_h=(SECONDS/3600%24)) + (_s=(SECONDS%60))"
_timehm='${_x[_tsub]}$_h:${_m}'
_timehms='${_x[_tsub]}$_h:$_m:${_s}'
_timedhms=$_Y'/'$_M'/'$_D" "'${_x[_tsub]}$_h:$_m:${_s}'
_hn=`hostname`
typeset -u _hn
_un=`who am i | awk '{print $1}'`
typeset -u _un
export PS1="$_timedhms
"'['$_un']'$_hn':${PWD#$HOME/} $ '
set +o allexport
```

Now, my prompt is two lines as such:

```
2014/08/06 12:34:56
[myusername]machinename:/present/working/directory
```

Comment: `.profile` is processed once and for all when you log in. `.envfile` is processed each time you start an interactive shell.